# How to create a new sequential timestamp column in a CSV file using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sample CSV file with columns as shown below.

```
col1,col2
1,57.5
2,24.0
3,56.7
4,12.5
5,75.5
```

I want a new `Timestamp` column in the `HH:mm:ss` format and the timestamp should keep on the increase by seconds as shown below.

```
col1,col2,ts
1,57.5,00:00:00
2,24.0,00:00:01
3,56.7,00:00:02
4,12.5,00:00:03
5,75.5,00:00:04
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose a solution based on `pyspark`. The `scala` implementation should be almost transparent.

My idea is to create a column filled with a unique timestamps (here 1980 as an example but does not matter) and add seconds based on your first column (row number). Then, you just reformat the timestamp to only see hours

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df = (df
 .withColumn("ts", psf.unix_timestamp(timestamp=psf.lit('1980-01-01 00:00:00'), format='YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
 .withColumn("ts", psf.col("ts") + psf.col("i") - 1)
 .withColumn("ts", psf.from_unixtime("ts", format='HH:mm:ss'))
)
df.show(2)
+---+----+---------+
|  i|   x|       ts|
+---+----+---------+
|  1|57.5| 00:00:00|
|  2|24.0| 00:00:01|
+---+----+---------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

## Data generation

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,57.5),
(2,24.0),
(3,56.7),
(4,12.5),
(5,75.5)], ['i','x'])
df.show(2)
+---+----+
|  i|   x|
+---+----+
|  1|57.5|
|  2|24.0|
+---+----+
only showing top 2 rows
```

## Update: if you don't have a row number in your csv (from your comment)

In that case, you will need `row_number` function.

This is not straightforward to number rows in Spark because the data are distributed on independent partitions and locations. The order observed in the csv will not be respected by `spark` when mapping file rows to partitions. I think it would be better not to use `Spark` to number your rows in your csv if the order in the file is important. A pre-processing step based on `pandas` with a loop over all your files, to take it one at a time, could make it work.

Anyway, I can propose you a solution **if you don't mind having row order different from the one in your csv stored in disk**.

```py
import pyspark.sql.window as psw
w = psw.Window.partitionBy().orderBy("x")
(df
 .drop("i")
  .withColumn("i", psf.row_number().over(w))
  .withColumn("Timestamp", psf.unix_timestamp(timestamp=psf.lit('1980-01-01 00:00:00'), format='YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
 .withColumn("Timestamp", psf.col("Timestamp") + psf.col("i") - 1)
 .withColumn("Timestamp", psf.from_unixtime("Timestamp", format='HH:mm:ss'))
 .show(2)
     )
+----+---+---------+
|   x|  i|Timestamp|
+----+---+---------+
|12.5|  1| 00:00:00|
|24.0|  2| 00:00:01|
+----+---+---------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

In terms of efficiency this is bad (it's like collecting all the data in master) because you don't use `partitionBy`. In this step, using `Spark` is overkill.

You could also use a temporary column and use this one to order. In this particular example it will produce the expected output but not sure it works great in general

```py
w2 = psw.Window.partitionBy().orderBy("temp")
(df
 .drop("i")
 .withColumn("temp", psf.lit(1))
  .withColumn("i", psf.row_number().over(w2))
  .withColumn("Timestamp", psf.unix_timestamp(timestamp=psf.lit('1980-01-01 00:00:00'), format='YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
 .withColumn("Timestamp", psf.col("Timestamp") + psf.col("i") - 1)
 .withColumn("Timestamp", psf.from_unixtime("Timestamp", format='HH:mm:ss'))
 .show(2)
     )
+----+----+---+---------+
|   x|temp|  i|Timestamp|
+----+----+---+---------+
|57.5|   1|  1| 00:00:00|
|24.0|   1|  2| 00:00:01|
+----+----+---+---------+
only showing top 2 rows
```

Comment: Hi Linog, What if I don't have the "I" (i.e col1) column. This is sample dataset. I don't have the "I" column in the original dataset

Comment: Do you have a column to partition or order your data ? I guess it requires `psf.row_number` that requires a window function. The concept of row numbering is not natural in `spark` where you don't have all the rows in the same partition. It is possible to find a hack but this might be inefficient, especially with large datasets

Comment: No. I don't have any column to partition. I have 100 files to manipulate this TS column and merge them into one.

Comment: I updated the answer. To create row numbers, spark is probably not the best tool

Comment: Thank you. I will follow your instructions.

Comment: Your're welcome. If the answer suits you, could you accept it [see guidelines if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your steps very well works for me. I just converted your steps to scala.